# How to play an video in a view of particular width and length in iOS 5

Tags: ios5, video, xcode4.5

I am trying to run a video in a view of `frame (0, 80, 320, 220)` which is the subview of
`self.view`

```
MPMoviePlayerViewController *moviePlayerViewController = [[MPMoviePlayerViewController alloc] initWithContentURL:url];
moviePlayerViewController.view.frame = myview.bounds;
[self presentMoviePlayerViewControllerAnimated:moviePlayerViewController];
moviePlayerViewController.moviePlayer.controlStyle = MPMovieControlStyleFullscreen;
moviePlayerViewController.moviePlayer.shouldAutoplay = YES;
[moviePlayerViewController.moviePlayer prepareToPlay];
moviePlayerViewController.moviePlayer.fullscreen=YES;
```

... it works fine if i replace `myview` with `self.view` which is  **320 x 480** pixels ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://devimages.apple.com/iphone/samples/bipbop/gear1/prog_index.m3u8"];



moviePlayerController = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL:url];
CGRect viewInsertRect = CGRectMake(0, 100, 320, 190);
[moviePlayerController.view setFrame:viewInsertRect];
[self.view addSubview:moviePlayerController.view];
[moviePlayerController play];
```